# Is there a substitute for a class inside a class CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So here is my HTML/CSS code:

```js
        function setVisibility() {
            var password = document.getElementById('password');
            var icon = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
            if(password.type === 'password') {
                password.type = 'text';
            } else {
                password.type = 'password';
            }
        }
```

```css
        input {
            border-color: #888;
            border-left: none;
            border-right: none;
            border-top: none;
        }
        input:focus {
            border-bottom-color: #0000ff;
            outline: none;
        }
        .password {
            float: left;
        }
        .show {
            color: #888;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }
```

```html
    <input type="text" placeholder="Full name">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="email" placeholder="Email address">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="password" id="password" class="password" placeholder="Password">
    <br>
    <p class="show" onclick="setVisibility();">Show</p>
```

My goal is to make the "Show" text turn blue (#0000ff) when the Password input box is clicked, then turn gray/grey (#888) when it is clicked off. I tried using `.password:focus .show {}`, but that didn't work. If there is an alternative, that would be very helpful.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

as was mentioned before, you should use sibling, check the link in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63803255/12184135) and check this [example](https://codepen.io/giana/pen/dWJzMK/).

It should be something like:

```js
        function setVisibility() {
            var password = document.getElementById('password');
            var icon = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
            if(password.type === 'password') {
                password.type = 'text';
            } else {
                password.type = 'password';
            }
        }
```

```css
        input {
            border-color: #888;
            border-left: none;
            border-right: none;
            border-top: none;
        }
        input:focus {
            border-bottom-color: #0000ff;
            outline: none;
        }
        .password {
            float: left;
        }
        .password:focus ~.show{
            color: red;
        }
        .show {
            color: #888;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }
```

```html
    <input type="text" placeholder="Full name">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="email" placeholder="Email address">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="password" id="password" class="password" placeholder="Password">
    <br>
    <p class="show" onclick="setVisibility();">Show</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `+` operator in the selector to indicate when one element comes immediately after another.

In your example, the password input is followed by a `br` and then the element you want to select - we can select this when password as focus as follows:

```
.password:focus + br + .show {
    color: #0000ff;
}
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

**Working Snippet:**

```js
function setVisibility() {
  var password = document.getElementById('password');
  var icon = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  if (password.type === 'password') {
    password.type = 'text';
  } else {
    password.type = 'password';
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  border-color: #888;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
  display:block;
}

input:focus {
  border-bottom-color: #0000ff;
  outline: none;
}

.password {
  float: left;
}

.show {
  color: #888;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.password:focus + br + .show {
    color: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
    <input type="text" placeholder="Full name">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="email" placeholder="Email address">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="password" id="password" class="password" placeholder="Password">
    <br>
    <p class="show" onclick="setVisibility();">Show</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may want to use a sibling selector.  .password:focus ~ .show {}

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator